# matlab get neighbours on matrix

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, nearest-neighbor

I have a simple matrix:

```
1  2  3  4
5  6  7  8
8  9  10 11
12 13 14 15
```

I need to loop through each element and build a new matrix with 3 of its surrounding elements (the one to the right, bottom right and bottom). So I will end up with an array like so:

```
1  2  6  5
2  3  7  6
3  4  8  7
```

I managed to do this but when I need to jump to the row below I can't seem to figure out how to do it. for the next row it should be:

```
5  6  9  8
6  7  10 9 
...
```

Any ideas?

Comment: And you skip last column and last row in the original matrix, right?

Comment: yes that's it, i won't need that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
[m n] = size(A);
[jj ii] = ndgrid(1:m-1, 1:n-1); %// rows and columns except last ones
kk = sub2ind([m n], ii(:),jj(:)); %// to linear index
B = [ A(kk) A(kk+m) A(kk+m+1) A(kk+1) ] %// pick desired values with linear index
```

In your example:

```
B =
     1     2     6     5
     2     3     7     6
     3     4     8     7
     5     6     9     8
     6     7    10     9
     7     8    11    10
     8     9    13    12
     9    10    14    13
    10    11    15    14
```

Answer (score 1):

My favourite `bsxfun` being put to work here -

```
[M,N] = size(A); %// A is Input
ind =  bsxfun(@plus,[1:M-1],[(0:N-2).*M]') %//'
out = A(bsxfun(@plus,ind(:),[0 M M+1 1]))  %// Desired output
```

Output using the sample input from question -

```
out =
     1     2     6     5
     2     3     7     6
     3     4     8     7
     5     6     9     8
     6     7    10     9
     7     8    11    10
     8     9    13    12
     9    10    14    13
    10    11    15    14
```